# OGR2OGR ERROR 1: Non contiguous curves

Tags: qgis, ogr2ogr

I am using ogr2ogr to move data between a file geodatabase and a postgres database with postgis installed.

the layer is returning the error: ERROR 1: Non contiguous curves

Googling the error does not turn up results that are helpful from what I can see. My understanding is that fgdb implementation in ogr2ogr is a little limited as the standard from ESRI is closed source.

I wanted to ask if anyone has more information or a solution for this error.

For my purposes, I solved the error and some other errors due to ring self intersections by using qgis to export to geopackage and then uploading via the qgis DB Manager.

```
>>> ogr2ogr --version 
>>> GDAL 3.1.4, released 2020/10/20
```

```
"SELECT VERSION();"

 PostgreSQL 12.7 (Ubuntu 12.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit
```

Comment: Error seems to mean that GDAL is finding invalid geometries. If ESRI considers that everything is fine then GDAL developers might be interested if you could isolate the problematic geometries and share them.

Comment: yeah agreed, I thought I'd give this some time and then follow up on the gdal mailing list to see if anyone has more info or would like a close look at the geoms.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `-MakeValid` tag when using ogr2ogr?  From the documetation
https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html

> -**makevalid** Run the OGRGeometry::MakeValid() operation, followed by OGRGeometryFactory::removeLowerDimensionSubGeoms(), on geometries to
> ensure they are valid regarding the rules of the Simple Features
> specification.

May not work as it appears the MakeValid operation tries to keep the position of the vertices.  But it is worth a try.